# Xcode server v3.2.1 copy assets after integration

Tags: xcode, xcode-bots, xcode-server

Haven't been able to find decent documentation on how to write bot scripts and Xcode Server has changed quite a bit in regards to folders and permissions.. basically just want to copy my .ipa and dSYM to another folder but when the script runs it returns:

cp: /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/IntegrationAssets/4f7c7e65532389e2a741d29758466c18-[Product NAME Here]/15/Archive.xcarchive.zip: No such file or directory

If I execute the copy after the integration is complete (not in the script) it works fine.. so my question is how/when do I copy the assets over in the "after integration" script of the bot? when are the files ready?

Thanks

My sample after integration script:

```
echo "Post"
set
echo

echo
echo /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/IntegrationAssets/$XCS_BOT_ID-$XCS_BOT_NAME/$XCS_INTEGRATION_NUMBER/Archive.xcarchive.zip
echo
echo "/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/IntegrationAssets/$XCS_BOT_ID-$XCS_BOT_NAME/$XCS_INTEGRATION_NUMBER/$XCS_PRODUCT"
echo

ASSETS_HOME="/tmp/XCS/$XCS_BOT_ID-$XCS_BOT_NAME/$XCS_INTEGRATION_NUMBER"

echo $ASSETS_HOME

mkdir -p "$ASSETS_HOME/"

cp -r "/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/IntegrationAssets/$XCS_BOT_ID-$XCS_BOT_NAME/$XCS_INTEGRATION_NUMBER/Archive.xcarchive.zip" "$ASSETS_HOME"

cp -r "/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/IntegrationAssets/$XCS_BOT_ID-$XCS_BOT_NAME/$XCS_INTEGRATION_NUMBER/$XCS_PRODUCT" "$ASSETS_HOME"

cd "$ASSETS_HOME"

unzip Archive.xcarchive.zip
```

Comment: I have the same problem, after integration i can download .ipa throught Xcode, but i cant find this file on server location. Have you resolve your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't resolved this problem, now using TeamCity :(

Comment: Hi. I have the same problem, did you resolved the problem?

Comment: I think at this point, after the archiving the file still doesnt exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ${XCS_OUTPUT_DIR} to find results of the builds including the IPA file.

I use "${XCS_OUTPUT_DIR}/${XCS_PRODUCT}" for the ipa.